# Finding Volume of Rugby Ball

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, conic-sections, volume

I am asked to find the volume of rugby ball whose surface is given by the ellipsoid:

$$\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{z^2}{9} = 1$$

I am having trouble figuring out which coordinate system I should use. Is it possible to solve the triple integral of the volume by just using cartesian co-ordinates, without making conversions to the spherical or cylindrical coordinate system?

Comment: Just to clarify: Is your question "Can a certain triple integral written with rectangular coordinates be integrated as-is?" Or do you just want to know how to find the volume?

Comment: My question is more "Can a certain triple integral written with rectangular coordinates be integrated as-is?", however someone below gave a great explanation of how to find the volume without integrals, and I replied because I was curious to see if I also understood that method of calculating the volume. @pjs36

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shape is a unit sphere that has been scaled by factors of $2,2$, and $3$ in the $x, y$, and $z$ directions. The volume is scaled by the same factors. So:
$$
V = 2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\frac43\pi1^3 = 16\pi
$$

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly, if I was given instead to calculate the volume of $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9} =  4$, would I then find the volume by: 

$ V=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdot\frac{4}{3} \pi \space 4^3 $ ?

Comment: @mnmakrets The constant on the right is $r^2$ (because a sphere of radius $r$ is given by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$), so in that case, the radius would be $2$. This would have the effect of scaling the volume by $2^3=8$; i.e., the new volume would be $V=2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\frac43\pi\cdot2^3$. You might want to try doing the same exercise in a smaller dimension so that you can draw diagrams and see what's going on. (For instance, try finding the area of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=1$. Then compare that to $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}=4$.)

Answer (score 7):

You can also find this volume by rotating the region inside the ellipse $\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1$ about the z-axis:

$\displaystyle V=2\int_0^3\pi(R(z))^2dz=2\pi\int_0^3 4\big(1-\frac{z^2}{9}\big)dz=8\pi\bigg[z-\frac{z^3}{27}\bigg]_0^3=16\pi.$

Answer (score 4):

You can use spherical coordinates by making the transformation $u=\frac{x}{2}$, $v=\frac{y}{2}$ and $w=\frac{z}{3}$. So you will be integrating the Jacobian over the unit ball!

Comment: Once I substituted those values into the equation it simplifies down to, $u+v+w=1$. To convert to spherical coordinates now, having made this substitution, can still I use the cartesian coordinate relation with the spherical coordinate system? i.e. since $z=3w$ does $w= \frac{\rho cos\phi}{3}$ and so on?

Comment: It's $u^{2}+v^{2}+w^{2}=1$

Comment: Oh right, would also converting the cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates using the relation that I stated in my first comment be an efficient approach to finding the volume using integration?

Answer (score 1):

Notice,

In general, the volume of ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ is $$=\frac{4\pi}{3}(abc)$$

Hence, the volume of ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=1\iff \frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}+\frac{1^2}{3^2}=1$ is $$=\frac{4\pi}{3}(2\cdot2\cdot 3)$$  $$=\frac{48\pi}{3}$$ $$=\color{blue}{16\pi}$$

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly, as I asked @Théophile who had given a similar answer, if I was given instead to calculate the volume of $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=4$ , would I then find the volume by: $V=2⋅2⋅3⋅\frac{4}{3} π 4^3 $?

Comment: No, in this case, we have $$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4}+\frac{z^2}{9}=4\iff  \frac{x^2}{4^2}+\frac{y^2}{4^2}+\frac{z^2}{6^2}=1$$ $a=4, b=4, c=6$ then the volume $$V=\frac{4\pi}{3}(4\cdot4\cdot6)=128\pi$$

Comment: "Notice, <the general formula>. Put numbers in."<-- Really? This answer is equivalent to "To find the solution, know the answer. Now you know the solution." It doesn't address the asker's question at all, at best it could be a comment.